# Percona Xtradb Cluster nodes won't start

Tags: cluster-computing, percona, galera, xtradb

I setup percona_xtradb_cluster-56 with three nodes in the cluster. To start the first cluster, i use the following command and it starts just fine:

```
#/etc/init.d/mysql bootstrap-pxc
```

The other two nodes however fail to start when i start them normally using the command:

```
#/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

The error i am getting is "The server quit without updating the PID file". The error log contains this message:

```
Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit 150605 22:10:29 
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended.
```

The cluster nodes are running all Ubuntu 14.04. When i use percona-xtradb-cluster5.5, the cluster ann all the nodes run just fine as expected. But i need to use version 5.6 because i am also using GTID which is only available in version 5.6 and not supported in earlier versions.

I was following these two percona documentation to setup the cluster:
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/installation.html#installation

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/howtos/ubuntu_howto.html

Any insight or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem, mine gives Operation not permitted error :[ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'joiner' --address '10.10.0.73' --auth '"msen:Memo3480$”' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' --defaults-group-suffix '' --parent '18393'  '' : 1 (Operation not permitted)

In 2nd node, it also deletes the /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock   file   

Is that a percona 5.6 bug?

Comment: Hi user2706112. I was running my cluster using Virtual box Vms and the problem happened to be a lack of disk space and memory allocated to my VMs. But here is my cluster config if it helps:                                                
    wsrep_cluster_address = gcomm://ip1, ip2,ip3
    wsrep_cluster_name = db_cluster
    wsrep_provider = /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so      # for Ubuntu
    wsrep_provider_options = "gcache.size=4G"
    wsrep_slave_threads = 32
    wsrep_sst_auth = "username:password"
    wsrep_sst_method = xtrabackup-v2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to memory, as "The Georgia" writes. There should be at least 500MB for default setup and bootstrapping. See here  http://sysadm.pp.ua/linux/px-cluster.html